# How can you select a random element from a list, and have it be removed?

Tags: python, random

Let's say I have a list of colours, `colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple']`.
I then wish to call this python function that I hope exists, `random_object = random_choice(colours)`.
  Now, if random_object holds 'blue', I hope `colours = ['red', 'green', 'purple']`.

Does such a function exist in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, if you want it removed because you want to do this again and again, you might want to use `random.shuffle()` in the random module.

`random.choice()` picks one, but does not remove it.

Otherwise, try:

```
import random

# this will choose one and remove it
def choose_and_remove( items ):
    # pick an item index
    if items:
        index = random.randrange( len(items) )
        return items.pop(index)
    # nothing left!
    return None
```

Answer (score 7):

one way:

```
from random import shuffle

def walk_random_colors( colors ):
  # optionally make a copy first:
  # colors = colors[:] 
  shuffle( colors )
  while colors:
    yield colors.pop()

colors = [ ... whatever ... ]
for color in walk_random_colors( colors ):
  print( color )
```