# How to merge two elements of two lists in python at random and ensure resulting entries are all unique?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, A and B, with an equal number of elements, although the elements in each list are not necessarily distinct.

I would like to form a new list by coupling the elements from A and B at random (the random pairing is important).

However, I also need to make sure that each pair in the resulting list is unique.

So far, I've been approaching the problem as follows, which works for small lists, but clearly is not suited to larger lists with many combinations.

```
from random import shuffle

# Create a list of actors and events for testing
events = ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P7']
actors = ['IE','IE','ID','ID','IA','IA','IA','IC','IB','IF','IG','IH','IH','IA']

# Randomize the elements of each list
shuffle(events)
shuffle(actors)

# Merge the two lists into a new list of pairs
edgelist = zip(events,actors)

# If the new list of pairs has all unique elements, then it is a good solution, otherwise try again at random
x = set(edgelist)

if len(edgelist) == len(x):
  break
else:
  while True:
    shuffle(events)
    shuffle(actors)
    edgelist = zip(events,actors)
    x = set(edgelist)
    if len(edgelist) == len(x):
      break

# Display the solution
print 'Solution obtained: '
for item in edgelist:
  print item
```

Can anyone suggest a modification or alternative approach that would scale to larger input lists?

Thanks for the helpful replies.

**Update**

Turns out this is a more challenging problem than originally thought.  I think I now have a solution.  It may not scale incredibly well but works fine for small or medium sized lists.  It checks to see whether a solution is possible before starting, so assumptions about the distribution of the input lists aren't necessary.  I also included a few lines of code to show that the frequency distributions of the resulting list match the original.

```
# Randomize the elements
shuffle(events)

# Make sure a solution is possible
combinations = len(set(events))*len(set(actors))
assert combinations >= len(events) and combinations >= len(actors) and len(events) == len(actors), 'No soluton possible!'

# Merge the two lists into a new list of pairs (this will contain duplicates)
edgelist = zip(events,actors)

# Search for duplicates
counts = collections.Counter(edgelist)
duplicates = [i for i in counts if counts[i] > 1]
duplicate_count = len(duplicates)

while duplicate_count > 0:

  # Get a single duplicate to address
  duplicate = duplicates[0]

  # Find the position of the duplicate in the in edgelist
  duplicate_pos = edgelist.index(duplicate)

  # Search for a replacement
  swap = choice(edgelist)
  swap_pos = edgelist.index(swap)

  if (swap[0],duplicate[1]) not in edgelist: 
    edgelist[duplicate_pos] = (swap[0],duplicate[1])
    edgelist[swap_pos] = (duplicate[0],swap[1])

  # Update duplicate count
  counts = collections.Counter(edgelist)
  duplicates = [i for i in counts if counts[i] > 1]
  duplicate_count = len(duplicates)


# Verify resulting edgelist and frequency distributions

print 'Event Frequencies: '
print sorted([y for (x,y) in list(collections.Counter(events).items())], reverse=True)

print 'Edgelist Event Frequencies: '        
print sorted([y for (x,y) in list(collections.Counter([x for (x,y) in edgelist]).items())], reverse=True)

print 'Actor Frequencies: '        
print sorted([y for (x,y) in list(collections.Counter(actors).items())], reverse=True)

print 'Edgelist Actor Frequencies: '        
print sorted([y for (x,y) in list(collections.Counter([y for (x,y) in edgelist]).items())], reverse=True)

assert len(set(edgelist)) == len(events) == len(actors)
```

Comment: If you use a set for "edgelist", the lookup that you have to do on *every* pair you try will be a lot faster.

Comment: I think you need to add the information about the input data you had in your 2nd update -- it's essential information.

Comment: @martineau I posted a new solution that will won't run if these assumptions aren't met, to make the answer more general.

Comment: @sail3005 There are still some serious problems with your updated solution. 1) by choosing a random element to swap, you're not gaining any randomness, but it can happen that you *never* reach a solution, even when there is one. 2) everytime you use Counter and "pair not in edgelist", you're sweeping the full array. And, since you do this an unpredictable number of times (because of the use of "choice"), it's hard to even tell how this performs. I've updated my answer with a recursive version that's guaranteed to find a solution, if there is one. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no reason for you to shuffle *both* lists. The pairing will not get "more random".

Update: I've posted a different solution than my original one. It's recursive, and is guaranteed to always return a valid answer, or None if one is not possible.

```
from random import shuffle

def merge(events, actors, index=None):
    """Returns list of unique pairs of events and actors, none of which may on index"""
    if len(events) == 0:
        return []
    if index is None:
        index = set()

    merged = None
    tried_pairs = set()
    for event in events:
        for i, actor in enumerate(actors):
            pair = (event, actor)
            if pair not in index and pair not in tried_pairs:
                new_index = index.union([pair])
                rest = merge(events[1:], actors[:i]+actors[i+1:], new_index)

                if rest is not None:
                    # Found! Done.
                    merged = [pair] + rest
                    break
                else:
                    tried_pairs.add(pair)
        if merged is not None:
            break

    return merged


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _events = ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P7']
    _actors = ['IE','IE','ID','ID','IA','IA','IA','IC','IB','IF','IG','IH','IH','IA']
    shuffle(_events)
    edgelist = merge(_events, _actors)

    if edgelist is not None:
        print 'Solution obtained: '
        for item in edgelist:
            print item
    else:
        print 'No possible solution with these events and actors.'
```

Note: the "index" variable is similar to checking edgelist, on the OP's solution. The "tried_pairs" variable is just an optimisation for each specific recursion step, to avoid retrying the same pair over and over again (if, for instance, there are several consecutive identical items in actors).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work OK, however I'm not completely sure how well it will scale...

```
# Create tuples of lists of actors and events for testing
testcases = [
    (['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P7'],
     ['IE','IE','ID','ID','IA','IA','IA','IC','IB','IF','IG','IH','IH','IA']),

    (['P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2'],
     ['IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID']),

    (['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','PA','PB','PC','PD','PE'],
     ['IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','IE','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID','ID']),
]

events, actors = testcases[0]

import random

def random_choice(items):
    """ yield list items in random order """
    items = items[:]  # preserve input argument
    random.shuffle(items)
    while items:
        yield items.pop()

pairs = set()
for event in random_choice(events):
    for index in random_choice(range(len(actors))):
        pair = (event, actors[index])
        if pair not in pairs:  # unique?
            pairs.add(pair)
            actors.pop(index)
            break

# Display the solution (in sorted order)
print 'Solution obtained has %d unique pairs: ' % len(pairs)
for item in sorted(list(pairs)):
    print item
```

I used ideas from both the answers to the question [How can you select a random element from a list, and have it be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791400/how-can-you-select-a-random-element-from-a-list-and-have-it-be-removed).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a hybrid between this answer and @rbp that guaranteed the final list would match the length of the input list.

Comment: @sail3005: I'd like to see the hybrid answer you came up with -- btw you can answer your own question on SO. I'd like to see how you guarantee the two lists have the same length because it seems to me that there are cases where that's impossible (as illustrated in the second and last [unreferenced] testcases in my answer).

Comment: @sail3005: (Without going into too many details) there's a significant bug in the code in your update -- the pairs it generates are not unique -- which is why it may appear to you to be able to do the impossible. Apart from that, it also does not look to me like it would scale very well.

Comment: Care to explain how...?  The pairs might not be unique but a new pair can only be added to the resulting list if it isn't already present.

Comment: Okay...the code I posted won't work if there aren't enough  _possible_ pairs to fill the length of the original lists with unique pairs. E.g. if each input list is filled with copies of the same object, `actors = [A,A,A]`, `events = [B,B,B]` would clearly not produce three unique pairs in a new list.  However the data I have (bipartite, undirected graphs) are structured such that there will always be enough unique possible pairs.  Apologies for the omission.  I'll note that in the post.

Comment: @sail3005: OK, here's what I noticed -- the test for whether the event/actor pair is not already in `edgelist` is always true because it looks for a tuple of them but inserts them as a sublist when they're not found.  As far as scaling poorly goes, since `edgelist` is a list rather than a set (or dict), the `not in` operation does a relatively slow linear search instead of a much faster hashing operation. IMHO, if there aren't enough possible pairs to match the input length, the procedure should handle it gracefully -- not provide the wrong answer or go into an infinite loop, for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Create a list of actors and events for testing
events = ['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P7']
actors = ['IE','IE','ID','ID','IA','IA','IA','IC','IB','IF','IG','IH','IH','IA']

# Randomize the elements
shuffle(events)

# Merge the two lists into a new list of pairs
edgelist = zip(events,actors)

# remove duplicates
x = set(edgelist)

# If there were not enough unique elements : add new ones as needed.
while len(x)<len(edgelist):
    x.add((choice(events), choice(actor)))

# Display the solution
print 'Solution obtained: '
for item in x:
  print item
```

Comment: You are not consuming the actors or events,`choice` may pick them more o less times than listed.

Comment: @dugres I like this updated solution.  It's very simple and works fast enough for my purposes.  Thanks.

Comment: @sail3005 you do realise that 1) this may never end (same problem KurzedMetal mentioned), and 2) you could be re-using elements from events or actors that have already been consumed and should not be reused?

Comment: @rbp Yes, I do now.  I posted a new solution up top that seems to be working.