# Select unique value from list

Tags: python, random, python-2.7, unique

What I am trying to do is, have a list of characters,each of which is a procedure, then I want to pick randomly (or pseudo randomly, it doesn't matter) from this list, and execute that procedure, then I want to be able to run the it again, and not get the same value,for example if I have five values I want to be able to run it 5 times, then the 6th time I run it, it returns nothing. Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import*
from random import randint
Characters=[Percy,Annabeth,Leo,Chuck,Sarah]
Used = []
def callback():
    end = len(Characters)-1
    rando = randint(0,end)
    Characters[rando]
    for i in Characters:
         if Characters[rando] in Used:
            print 'This has already been used'
         else:
            Characters[rando]()
            Used.append(Characters[rando])
            break


game = Tk()
game.geometry('50x50+700+100')
Button1 = Button(game,text = '1',command =lambda:callback() )
Button1.pack(side=LEFT)


game.mainloop()
```

I am trying to get

```
callback()
```

to run properly, I have tried what you see but I have also tried

```
if Characters[rando] in Used:
    print 'This has already been used'
else: 
   Characters[rando]
   Used.append(Characters[rando])
```

in both cases it will run the same procedure multiple times, for example, 'Leo' might be executed 3 times in a row. I searched for hours for a way to do this, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: This has been answered well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791400/how-can-you-select-a-random-element-from-a-list-and-have-it-be-removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would `shuffle` the `Characters`:

```
Characters = [Percy,Annabeth,Leo,Chuck,Sarah]
random.shuffle(Characters)
```

Now when you run your callback, you `pop` one character out:

```
def callback():
    try:
       C = Characters.pop()  #popping the last one is more efficient than the first.
    except IndexError:
       return None

    return C()
```

Since this destroys `Characters`, you may want to keep a copy of it around to reset if you need to:

```
 random.shuffle(Characters)
 Characters_save = Characters[:]

 def reset_characters():
     Characters[:] = Characters_save[:]
```

Comment: You don't need to specify an index for `.pop()`, just let it pop the last, as it's the most efficient

Comment: @JonClements -- I changed it to `.pop(-1)` for efficiency, but you're right.  There's no need to specify here.  Updated.

Comment: `shuffle` is also in-place so returns `None` and you need to save *before* shuffling...

Comment: @JonClements -- Thanks.  Forgot about that one.

Comment: I tried this, I got the error 'C = Characters.pop(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: @ChuckFulminata -- Sorry, that's because I forgot that `shuffle` does it's magic in place.  I've edited to fix that.

Comment: @ChuckFulminata -- The depends entirely on how you import it.  I was assuming a straight `import random` (just to make it more explicit where we're getting `shuffle` from).  But you could do `from random import shuffle` or even `from random import shuffle as qux`

Comment: I just used, `from random import*`

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested - but you could implement a basic class:

```
from random import shuffle

class CallNext(object):
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals[:]
        shuffle(self.vals)
        self.iter = iter(self.vals)
    def __call__(self):
        try:
            next(self.iter)()
        except StopIteration as e:
            pass # or do something smarter?
```

Another option instead of catching `StopIteration` would be to use:

```
next(self.iter, lambda: None)()
```

And then have:

```
Button1 = Button(game, text='1', command=CallNext(Characters) )
```